# What is the command line switch for Far Manager to open in a specified directory?

Tags: command-line, far-manager

What is the command line switch for Far Manager to open in a specified directory?

Answer (score 6):

There is no explicit switch for this, you just append the desired directory name.

Citing the built-in help (from FAR 1.7x, FAR 3.x has additional features in this respect):

> It is possible to specify at most two paths to folder, files or archives in the command line. The first path applies to the active panel, the second path - to the passive one:
>
> - if a folder or archive is specified, FAR will show its contents
> - if a file is specified, FAR will change to the folder where it
>     resides and place the cursor on the file, if it exists.

So, assuming your Windows is installed in `c:\windows`, you can start FAR with

```
far c:\windows c:\
```

and it will start with `c:\windows` in the active panel and `c:\` in the passive one.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a dot as an argument to indicate "current folder". If `far. exe` is globally available by, lets say, including it in the `PATH` environmental variable executing

```
far .
```

will open Far Manager and display the folder from which it was opened.

Answer (score 0):

You could type `cd c:\windows` in Far's command prompt and the active panel will change to it. Remember to escape paths that contain space character with double quotes as in command line.